# Maven: How to activate profile based on whether child module contains a file?

Tags: maven, profile, file-exists, activation

I’m using Maven 3.1.1 on Mac 10.9.1.  I want to activate a profile based on whether certain child modules contain a file.  I have tried the following

```
    <profile>
        <id>deploy-war-to-jboss</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${session.executionRootDirectory}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jboss.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <hostname>${jboss.remote.hostname}</hostname>
                        <port>${jboss.remote.port}</port>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy-to-jboss</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

but this profile doesn’t get activated when running “mvm clean install” despite the fact I’ve verified that the child modules in question contain the file.  I also tried ${project.basedir} without luck.  Any ideas how I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you define the profile in the parent POM (I guess) you should try this

```
${basedir}/name-of-your-child-module//src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Furthermore, you should try [running Maven in debug mode](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-verbose-option) to get more information at runtime:

```
mvm -X clean install
```

Comment: I have several child modules for which the condition will be satisfied.  What I'm trying to say in my profile is if the child module has a "web.xml" file, run the profile, otherwise, don't run it.  So I'm trying to avoid hard-coding of things.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If the profile is in the parent POM and all child module POMs inherit from it then you should be able to use `${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` because `${project.basedir}` is evaluated against the respective child module.